# Difference between -NS and -NAMESERVER

Tags: powershell, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I am writing a script to create the necerassary DNS records of a zone in PowerShell. Going through the documentation, I saw two properties for the [Add-DnsServerResourceRecord command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649925.aspx). One is `-NS`, and the other is `-NameServer`.

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between the two? And which one to use to set the NS records for the zone? As I see in the docs, they are not alieses for each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-NS` is a switch parameter that tells the cmdlet that you are adding an `NS` record to DNS.

`-Nameserver` is how you pass the value of the `NS` record.

Essentially `-NS` is required on the `NS` parameter set (because that's how that parameter set gets chosen). `-Nameserver` is only available in the `NS` parameter set, and it is also required in that set because it's the value you need to set.

So to set `NS` records for a zone, you need both.

This is similar to the relationship between `-Ptr` and `-PtrDomainName`.

Comment: Got it. Good explanation :) Thanks!